# Numpy arithmetic

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following code :

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([[3, 5, 1]])
print(x.shape) #get (1,3)
np.multiply(x.shape, 8) #get [ 8, 24]

print(*x.shape) # get 1 3
np.array((np.multiply(*x.shape), 8)) #get [3, 8]
```

Please explain why/how np.multiply(*x.shape, 8) get [3, 8] ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  `x,shape` is just a tuple.  Why multiply it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that by doing

```
np.multiply(*x.shape)
```

You are unpacking the tuple `(1,3)` using the `*` operator, and passing each element as an argument to `np.multiply`. So that results in `1*3` which is 3.

Then, you are just wrapping the result of that up into an array with `8`, so you end up with an array that is `[3, 8]`

Answer (score 0):

The `*` unpacks iterables. So if `x.shape` is `(1,3)` and you call `np.multiply(*x.shape)` you will actually call `np.multiply(1,3)` which gives `3`. The `8` is just hardcoded, so nothing special there.

Also, because you wrote it: the `8` is *not* an argument of `np.multiply` here.